# Is there a way to create share link on a website for Instagram?

Tags: javascript, social-media

I am trying to implement a button that users can click. It would take them to Instagram and start a new post with my website URL. I did it for Facebook using

```js
 window.open('https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=' + url.value)
```

Is there any simillar way of doing this with instagram?

Answer (score -2):

You can use a plugin that can do this automatically without coding. Try these plugins:
social sharing
social media auto push

Comment: Congrats on your first answer! Please try to be more specific, eg share the social media plugin name.